# url Change in core php

Tags: php, url, routes

I am using core PHP and I want to change URL.
This is my actual URL:

```
http://www.example.com/blogs/blog_single.php?title=Need-of-a-Professional
```

and I want that type of URL:

```
http://www.example.com/blogs/Need-of-a-Professional
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: It's called [pretty url](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049). Use .htaccess to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/]*)\.html$ /blogs/blog_single.php?title=$1 [L]
```

You can use online url rewrite tools to generate custom urls such as [this one](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is a get request and title is send in it.
To change it you have to change the method of form.
There will be other changes too as by doing this your previous code will not work properly.

Comment: your code
<form method="GET" action="http://www.example.com/blogs/blog_single.php?title=Need-of-a-Professional">
</form>  

now change it to


<form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com/blogs/Need-of-a-Professional">
</form>

Comment: there will be other changes also as your request is changing from get to post.For more help i have to take look over your code.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is on the basis of url path(condition) i have called the controller(means the page which i have to call in result):
Like in this code line on index.php $ctrlpath is the path upto the controller then $page is the page which i have to call one the basis of condition :-

```
$url_parts = parse_url(preg_replace('/\/{2,}/', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$url_path = $url_parts['path'];


/*This I have done in router.php*/
if($url_path == '/saving-calc/'){
    $page = 'tools/saving-calc';
}

require_once($ctrlpath.$page.'.php');
```

Then on your own controller you an append the title of your page in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You try this..

```
$url = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
//breaking the url and storing it as array based on '/'

array_pop($url); 
// last part of the url is removed from array in you case 'blog_single.php?title=Need-of-a-Professional' removed from array

array_push($url,'Need-of-a-Professional'); 
// pushed at last index
echo implode('/', $url); //converting array into url(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your .htaccess file with below.

> Options +FollowSymLinks
>      RewriteEngine On 
>      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
>      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
>      RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)*$ ./blog_single.php?title=$1

Answer (score 0):

You can generate htaccess by putting the dynamic url.

generate from here.
https://www.webconfs.com/web-tools/url-rewriting-tool/

Answer (score -3):

Yes,You will change easily URL manually.

Example:

```
<a href="index.php?id='1'&action='GET'">Click Me</a>
```